# Searching for Bold formatted Cells

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I am trying to set a range of cells between bold cells. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
With Worksheets("FC01.RPT")
.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2) = "Individual Rate Guest"
```

Instead of using "Individual Rate Guest", how can I write it so that it will look for a bold format?

Thanks!

Comment: the cod you have does not look for anything, it simply assigns a value to a cell.  What have you tried to search.  You will need to loop and find the bold cells.

Comment: Something like: `.Font.Bold = True` but as Scott Craner says, you'll need to loop through your cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would find the first two bold cells (offset to create a range between) in Column E of your worksheet regardless of content.  You can replace the `*` with text if you wanted bold text of a certain content.  As mentioned, if you wanted to find all bold cells, you would need to create a loop.

```
Sub FindBoldCells()

    Dim boldcell As Range
    Dim boldcell2 As Range

    Application.FindFormat.Clear

    Application.FindFormat.Font.Bold = True

    With Worksheets("FC01.RPT")

        Set boldcell = .Range("E:E").Find("*", SearchFormat:=True).Offset(1, 0)

        Set boldcell2 = .Range("E:E").Find("*", After:=boldcell, SearchFormat:=True).Offset(-1, 0)

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!